# What happens when Npgsql connection pool reaches Max

Tags: c#, npgsql

Both the name of the connection string parameter and this blog post - http://fxjr.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/npgsql-connection-pool-explained.html - lead me to believe that Npgsql wont exceed the MaxPoolSize value set in the connection string. However the docs (http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) say "Max size of connection pool. Pooled connections will be disposed of when returned to the pool if the pool contains more than this number of connections. Default: 20"

This suggests that the pool can actually grow larger than MaxPoolSize and it is in fact just a level at which Npgsql starts to aggressively remove connections from the pool as soon as they are returned.

I've been searching to try and find an answer but I can find out exactly what happens when you reach MaxPoolSize. Anyone else know?

edit: I should add we are using Npgsql 2.0.6.0 due to another dependency being supported only up to that version.

Comment: Why not just have a look at the source?  Should be easy enough to hunt down "MaxPoolSize".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this may be a copy paste issue regarding the minpoolsize. Npgsql doesn't create more than maxpoolsize connections. When this value is reached, new connection requests are queued until there is a free one.

Which issue are you depending on which only works on 2.0.6?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Francisco. No particular features depend upon 2.06, but we have a commercial data access layer we cant presently afford to upgrade which was built against 2.0.6. I may well try to run our tests with the latest version of npgsql in there.

How the pooling is handled is important for a change we are making that will unified what are presently a lot of separate sites into a single site. Taking lots of small app pools down into one larger pool.

Comment: OK, so you definitely should go to 2.0.11.93, because we made some improvements about connection pooling which gives 30% better performance according to user tests. Please, let me know if it works ok for you.